# HTML JQuery getJSON return [object Object]

Tags: jquery, html, getjson

Json data with this structure:

```
Title_day_hourminsec([
{"data":"x", "type":"y"},
{"data":"x", "type":"y"},
{"data":"x", "type":"y"},
{"data":"x", "type":"y"},
{"data":"x", "type":"y"},
{"data":"x", "type":"y"},
]);
```

from the call of jquery getJSON I'm not able to get the real content of the file, only got this is the html output:

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

this is the javascript snippet I've tried to get the json content:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("myremotedata",
      function(data){
      var items = [];

 $.each(data, function(key, val) {
items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
});
 $('<ul/>', {
'class': 'my-new-list',
html: items.join('')
}).appendTo('body');
        });
  });


</script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The data shown is not valid JSON. Is it supposed to be JSONP?

Comment: You get an array of objects. `[object Object]` is the **default string representation** of an object. If you want to display specific properties, then you have to [access them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators).

Comment: $.getJSON will parse the response automatically using JSON.parse() and that's why you end up with the JavaScript object. You can use $.get() instead if you need the response to be in JSON format unparsed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to modify your each loop like:

```
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.data + ' ' + val.type + '</li>');
});
```

You are getting `[object Object]` since in the each loop, the variable `val` is actually an object. You need to use the Javascript dot object notation like `val.data` or `val.type` to get the values of the each object.

Answer (score 0):

$.each() returns an index and the value at that index.

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    // value contains {"data":"x", "type":"y"}
});
```

you can then use value.data or value.type for populating your list.